# Get x number of last element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dom, domdocument

How to effectively get a certain number of elements from the end?

```
<div><span>1</span></div>
<div><div>looks like 2</div></div>
<div>three!!</div>
```

For example, how would I fetch the contents last 2 `div`s?

Comment: Your question is vague. How would you like to get the contents of the elements? Via PHP or Javascript? Where would you like to store the result?

Comment: I did tag PHP, but JavaScript or jQuery wouldn't hurt. @FilipposKarapetis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total = $("div").length;
    var last  = $("div").eq(total-1).html();
    var secondlast  = $("div").eq(total-2).html();
});
```

see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/irfandanish/jKsGb/)

Answer (score 1):

if you meant with JQuery it would be something like this (as how i understood your question)

```
var last = 5;
jQuery('body> div:nth-last-child('+(last+1)+') ~div')
```

Comment: Ohh! Is this tested? Thanks a heap!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an xpath query - which you can use both in Javascript or PHP:

```
*[position() > last() - 2]
```

You execute it relative to the context-node which is the parent here:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$context = $doc->documentElement;
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

$elements = $xp->query('*[position() > last() - 2]', $context);
var_dump($elements->length);

foreach($elements as $i => $element) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", $i, $doc->saveXML($element));
}
```

Output:

```
int(2)
0: <div>
    <div>looks like 2</div>
  </div>
1: <div>three!!</div>
```

Hope this helps. I took the right to beautify the XML. [Online Demo is here](https://eval.in/35170).

Comment: Looks good- but how would I output all the stuff the raw HTML? without all the 0: and int(2)

Comment: Can you sport the line where the numbers are output? If you look closely, I guess you'll see how that would work. I just put the numbers in, so that it better demonstrates that there are two results, in a real application you naturally leave those numbers out, for sure!

Comment: So... where does the int come from ?

Comment: ah that one, sorry, it's the `var_dump()` of the length property.